# set ItemTemplate for specific column of DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` and it is bound to `List<Person> people`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
}

public void ShowPeople()
{
     myDataGrid.ItemsSource = people;
}
```

It shows everything fine, but I want to show `Address` in `TextBox` inside the `DataGrid`.

I changed XAML code to this:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Address}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid>
```

this is not working. It is giving me an error.

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `Columns` property in your XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns> <-- This is missing in your code!
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Address}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do what in code behind? Create the entire `DataGrid` instead of using XAML?

Comment: Setting ItemTemplate to a column.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Maybe you should post a new question. Someone else might know :)